# Windows File Protection - is there a way to view what file(s) got modified?

Tags: windows-xp

Several users in my office all reported on the same day that they were getting "Windows File Protection" messages. It wasn't after windows updates or other software/drivers were pushed.

I generally assume driver updates and windows updates will cause this, and it is no cause for concern. This time, however, I'm curious what caused it.

Can anyone shed some light on this? How can I find which files were modified?

Comment: Whoa, there's another person on this site named J McKinnon?  I was just scanning recent questions, and just happened to notice the name next to this question and thought "hey, I didn't ask that!" and then realized it was indeed not me...  ;-)

Comment: Indeed - I noticed there being another McKinnon as well. I am surprised it didn't pick up my full name from Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System File Checker tool gives an administrator the ability to scan all the protected files to verify their versions. Use "sfc" command-line tool

UPD: in comments

Comment: This is good to know, but it still won't give me any information on which file(s) were modified. There may not be a better answer though, so if one doesn't come in then in a week I will accept...

Comment: My answer "sfc /SCANNOW" just tries to repair these files using an original CD. I found no tools to list changed files, sorry. The idea is to compare files in "%WinDir%\System32\Dllcache" with their digital signatures in "%Systemroot%\system32\catRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}".

Comment: accepted - it's worth pushing your above commentinto the answer, I think it's helpful. I also found http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/wfp.mspx was a nice summary